# Android PhoneGap: use res/drawable/img.png in html file

Tags: android, cordova

I am new one in phonegap, i want to display images from android res. drawable/img.png to my index.html file.

Is it possible in android phonegap? any one can explain clearly?

Comment: i create image folder under assets and i get images its working but i want drawable folder images, if i change the android devices small, medium resolution the images also will be set. i want to this type. is it any possibility is there?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to insert an image in your custom html file, you can use the images from res directory with no problem. This is on Android ICS.

```
img src="file:///android_res/drawable/myimage.png"
```

Android will pick the right image based on the dpi.

Answer (score 1):

create one folder like "images" in assets and we can acess images from assets like below code and u put that html also in assets folder

```
<img class="logo" alt="" src="images/logo.png"></img>
```

Comment: but, i want to use under res/drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi folder images depending different resolution size in android. is any possibility is there?

Comment: Yes. Put entries just like the above in each folder, referencing the appropriate copies of your image.

Answer (score 0):

img src="file:///android_res/drawable/myimage.png" is working fine